# Append text in NSTextView while not breaking Undo Stack

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsattributedstring, nstextview, nstextstorage

I have an NSTextView based application where I have various commands changing the text. In order to replace a portion I use the following snippet:

```
if ([textView shouldChangeTextInRange:range replacementString:string]) { //string
  [textStorage beginEditing];
  [textStorage replaceCharactersInRange:range withAttributedString:attributedString];
  [textStorage endEditing];
  [textView didChangeText];
}
```

My issue starts when I want to append at the end of the textview. In that case I cannot use `shouldChangeTextInRange:range replacementString:string` so I use :

```
textView.textStorage?.beginEditing()
self.textView.textStorage?.append(NSAttributedString(string: string))
self.textView.scrollToEndOfDocument(nil)
textView.textStorage?.endEditing()
textView.didChangeText()
```

While it works fine for attributes, Undo totally breaks. Any idea how I can fix that issue?

Comment: Hint: Use the `selectedRange` method of the `TextView` class effectively.

Comment: Why can't you use `shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementString:`?

Comment: I finally followed your advices and it worked. Thanks